# safari webdriver testing with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, web, safari, driver

I'm on a mac using javascript to test a Safari page using Selenium.  I have js opening a page, typing in a input field, clicking buttons...  But I need to test if data was brought in correctly by getting the value of dom elements.

I have tried:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('safari')
    .build();

driver.get('http://server.com/testPage.html')
    .then( () => driver.sleep( 2000 ))
    .then( () => driver.findElement( By.id('typeHere') ).sendKeys('webdriver'))
    .then( () => driver.sleep( 3000 ))
    .then( () => driver.findElement(  By.id('clickHere')  ).click() )
    .then( () => driver.sleep( 2000 ))
    .then( () => {
        let tmp = driver.findElement( By.id('typeHere') ).getAttribute('value');
        console.log('found:', tmp);
    })
    .then( () => driver.quit())
;
```

which logs:

```
found:  Promise { <pending> }
(node:10883) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError
```

the page that's being tested is

```
<html><body>
  <input id="typeHere" value="default"/><br/>
  <button id="clickHere" onclick="alert('a click, happy day!')">click me</button>
</body></html>
```

UPDATE.  this is working. I need to learn more about promises!

```
driver.get('http://server.com/testPage.html').then(run());

function run() {
  var foundValue = driver.findElement( By.id('typeHere') ).getAttribute('value');
  foundValue.then((value) => {
      if(value === 'default'){
         console.log("GOT IT!");
      }
  });
};
```

Comment: Please share the page that includes 'typeHere' element.

Comment: Are you sure you have the driver access at that particular line? It’s saying ‘nosession’